# Assgin Date To DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I Want to Assign Only Date to DateTime variable
and the DateTime variable sholud hold Date Only.

```
var date = DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime dt= date;
```

dt should hold Date only

how can i do that

Comment: `DateTime` **always** contains a time component, there is no way to store just a date in there. You can create a new `DateTime` using the constructor `DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day)` but it will contain the time at midnight.

Comment: it is so bad.... really i need it

Comment: try looking at MSDN on the DateTime for examples of what other properties you can access.. this pretty straight forward in regards to the documentation

Comment: Explain why you "really need it". Explain what you need it for. You have an XY problem, X being why you need this and Y being "I know, I'll use a DateTime without time". The latter is impossible, a DateTime _always_ has a time part, so please explain your original problem X and I'm sure there's an easier solution. Perhaps `DateTime.ToString(string format)` will do what you want.

Comment: What is wrong with `DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.Date`?

Comment: Its because of how `DateTime` is stored in memory. Its the number of ticks (100-nanosecond units) since the `DateTime` epoch, which is January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000. Since the underlying value is actually a time, the value is always itself a time.

Comment: Do you just want `Date dt = date.Date`?

Comment: yes i want dt hold only Date not datetime

Comment: Again, you can't. Explain why you want that.

Comment: then do something like this it's so simple 
`var date = DateTime.Now.Date;
 var dt = date.ToShortDateString();` return what you are looking for as a String

Comment: @CodeCaster what are you talking about it returns the Date only he doesn't want the time..

Comment: @MethodMan OP is asking for a DateTime. You give them a string. That may be what they need, but it isn't what they're asking for.

Comment: I know what he's asking for the problem is the OP doesn't understand the DateTime Structure ...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are satisfied with [`DateTime.Today`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
```

> An object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to
>   00:00:00.

If you want the date of any `DateTime` you can use it's [`Date` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime dateOfDateTime = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

> A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value
>   set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).

A `Datetime` always contains a time portion. You could use [`DateTime.ToShortDateString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx) to display it without time:

```
string dateOnly = Date.Today.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: I don't want Today i need any datetime variable

Comment: what do you mean you need any datetime variable.. give an example @peter_2011

Comment: @peter_2011: you can use `DateTime.Date` to get a DateTime where the time portion is "truncated". I've edited my answer.

Comment: Like the previous example i was wrote

Comment: @peter_2011 your previous example won't work.. I suggest that you take the time out to read the documentation as well as understand how the DateTime Structure works..

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers already a `DateTime` will always contain a date and a time part (even if the time part is set to 00:00:00).

If for whatever reasons that won't be suitable for you, you can always look at third party date and time APIs.

[Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) might be of particular interest to you and contains a struct with only date part in it.

> LocalDate is an immutable struct representing a date within the calendar, with no reference to a particular time zone or time of day.

Comment: Good recommendation.  Also along this line of thought, I am working on a [proposal to add `System.Date` as a data type to .NET Framework](https://github.com/mj1856/corefx-dateandtime).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a `DateTime` with just the date portion, you can just call `someDateTimeVariable.Date`. The time will always be set to *something*, but it's standard to set it to midnight if the time is not significant.

In your example, you might just do

```
DateTime dt = date.Date;
```

Comment: and how does this bring back only the Date..? it still has the Time portion in the dt object..

Comment: @MethodMan yes, but the time will be midnight. Documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).